# Hand Tracking python

Tags: python, pycharm

wrote this code following a youtube tutorial for hand tracking:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands()
mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

pTime = 0
cTime = 0

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = hands.process(imgRGB)
    # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for handLms in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for id, lm in enumerate(handLms.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                print(id, cx, cy)
                # if id == 4:
                cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 15, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

            mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
    pTime = cTime

    cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
                (255, 0, 255), 3)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

when I run this code I followed I get this error message:

```
C:\Users\gouri\PycharmProjects\opencv2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/gouri/PycharmProjects/opencv2/main.py
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gouri/PycharmProjects/opencv2/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
```

and yes I have installed all the packages correctly and my python version is up to date.

Comment: It is possible that the image does not load properly. In my usual case it's the camera connection that fails. Maybe you can check it.

Comment: yes, the assertation error looks like there is no data in your img , or None in that, just debug what you are getting in the img variable.

Answer (score 0):

having same error, but can't find any satisfactory solutions.
I answer I found was that, 'XNNPACK best runs on ARM x86 CPU.'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).